# Is digital certificate of PE(Portable Executable) file is in overlay of file?

Tags: reverse-engineering, portable-executable, malware, ollydbg, malware-detection

**Digital Certificate** is in the overlay of file or digital certificate is outside of a file

Answer (score 3):

Yes, technically, the certificate of an Executable is located in the overlay of the executable, which is, never mapped into memory.

Most of the time, Analysis tools separate/distinguish between the Certificate and the "rest" of the overlay (if available).

e.g. "pestudio" separates these logical entities...

[image]